# Does Argothian Elder and Maze of Ith really produce infinite mana during the attack phase?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

According to a comment in the [discussion of Argothian Elder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Discussion.aspx?multiverseid=21182):

> [Argothian Elder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Argothian%20Elder) plus [Maze of Ith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Maze%20of%20Ith) provides infinite mana during your attack phase.

How is that? In order for Argothian Elder to attack it has to tap, per rule 508.1f, and if Argothian Elder is tapped it can't be tapped again to activate the ability.

If you could attack and tap to active abilities simultaneously, it'd work, but I don't think you can.

So is the comment wrong or am I wrong?

Comment: The key thing here is that untapping the attacking elder does not make him stop attacking. Thus he can be targted by the maze multiple times during your attack phase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to tap them simultaneously for this to work. Once you have declared [Argothian Elder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Argothian%20Elder) as an attacker, you can do the following:

1: Tap [Maze of Ith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Maze%20of%20Ith) to untap [Argothian Elder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Argothian%20Elder)

2: Tap [Argothian Elder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Argothian%20Elder) to untap Maze of Ith and another land.

3: Tap that other land for mana.

4: Repeat as much as you want.

Answer (score 4):

you use [maze of ith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=maze%20of%20ith) to untap him.

then you use [argothian elder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=argothian%20elder) to untap [maze of ith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=maze%20of%20ith), and one extra land.

then you float a mana with that extra land, and repeat the process.  the result is 1 extra mana for free.

you can do this as much as you want.